# Why does the thumbnail I create have a larger file size than the original image?

Tags: php, image, google-maps

I want to save Google Maps images to my server.  Below is the code I am using to get and save these images, and the code for creating a thumbnail.  I'm using CodeIgniter for this.

```
//saving original image on server
$post = $_POST;
$file = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=".$post['w']."x".$post['h']."&sensor=false&markers=color:red|size:mid|".$post['lt'].",".$post['lg']."&&zoom=".$post['z']);

$filename = 'map_'.uniqid().'.png';
$name     = './assets/images/upload/'.$filename;
file_put_contents($name, $file);

// creating thumbnail 
$config_manip = array(
    'image_library' => 'gd2',
    'source_image' => './assets/images/upload/'.$filename,
    'new_image' => './assets/images/upload/thumb_'.$filename,
    'maintain_ratio' => false,
    'quality' => "10%",
    'width' => 480,
    'height' => 480 
);

$this->load->library('image_lib', $config_manip);
$this->image_lib->resize();
```

My problem is that the generated thumbnail image is much bigger in size then the original.  For comparison:

- [Original image](http://www.shadyab.com/patil/assests/images/upload/map_6063ed5dee2ddcd28fe19757daef5feae79c0e58.png)
- [Thumbnail image](http://www.shadyab.com/patil/assests/images/upload/thumb_map_6063ed5dee2ddcd28fe19757daef5feae79c0e58.png)

Why is the thumbnail bigger than the original?

Comment: Erhm. The original is 640×640. The thumbnail is 480×480. I can’t get what you expected.

Comment: since 480 < 640 i expect thumbnail to have smaller size .... right now original is about 13kb and thumbnail is 50kb !

Comment: Just a heads up that what you are trying to do is against the maps TOS https://developers.google.com/maps/terms 10.1.3 specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thumbnail you create has 4 times the bit depth of the original.  Reducing the bit depth will reduce the file size.

[image: Properties of original file] [image: Properties of thumbnail file]

---

***Edit:***

To reduce the bit-depth is quite simple, but I can't see any way to do this via CodeIgniter:

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng('./original.png');
imagetruecolortopalette($im, false, 256);
imagepng($im, './output.png');
```

However, this file is still larger than the original (~17KiB vs. ~13KiB). Running it through [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/) gets it down to ~13KiB, close to the original.

Answer (score 5):

The principal difference is that your original image contains a palette, whereas your thumbnail does not. So, instead of having to store an 8-bit index into a palette for each pixel, the thumbnail has to store 3 off 8-bit true colours for each pixel. You need a way to force a palettised thumbnail - i.e. use `imagecreate()` rather than `imagecreatetruecolor()` or call `imagetruecolortopalette()` prior to output.

Here is the analysis of each file:

[image]

Depending on the number of colours you choose to include in your palette, you will get different file sizes as follows:

```
Colours    Filesize (bytes)
=======    ================
10          3,380
16         12,199
32         12,415
64         36,581
128        36,825
256        42,013
```

Comment: That image analysis looks incredibly useful! What did you use to generate the `.txt` files?

Comment: @timclutton Hi Tim, I used ImageMagick like this: `identify -verbose image.jpg` it's great it tells you all the EXIF info, histogram, statistics etc. Then I compared them with `opendiff` on the Mac which is just brilliant too.

Comment: I keep meaning to dig into ImageMagick and this gives me even greater reason to. Superb, thank you Mark; have an upvote!